# glmnet not converging for lambda.min from cv.glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I ran a 20-fold `cv.glmnet` lasso model to obtain the "optimal" value for lambda. However, when I attempt to reproduce the results from `glmnet()`, the I get an error that reads:

```
Warning messages:
1: from glmnet Fortran code (error code -1); Convergence for 1th lambda
   value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger 
   lambdas returned 
2: In getcoef(fit, nvars, nx, vnames) :
   an empty model has been returned; probably a convergence issue
```

My code reads as such:

```
set.seed(5)
cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x[train,],y[train],family="binomial",nfolds=20,alpha=1,parallel=TRUE)
coef(cv.out)
bestlam <- cv.out$lambda.min
lasso.mod.best <- glmnet(x[train,],y[train],alpha=1,family="binomial",lambda=bestlam)
```

Now, the value of `bestlam` above is `2.976023e-05` so perhaps this is causing the problem? Is it a rounding issue on the value of lambda? Is there a reason why I can't reproduce the results directly from the `glmnet()` function? If I use a vector of lambda values in the similar range to this value of `bestlam`, I do not have any issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a single lambda to your `glmnet` (`lambda=bestlab`) which is a big no-no (you're attempting to train a model just using one lambda value).

From the `glmnet` documentation `(?glmnet)`:

```
lambda: A user supplied lambda sequence. Typical usage is to have the 
program compute its own lambda sequence based on nlambda and 
lambda.min.ratio. Supplying a value of lambda overrides this. WARNING: use 
with care. Do not supply a single value for lambda (for predictions after CV 
use predict() instead). Supply instead a decreasing sequence of lambda 
values. glmnet relies on its warms starts for speed, and its often faster to 
fit a whole path than compute a single fit.
```

Answer (score 2):

glmnet is a little tricky in that respect - you'll want to run your best model with a series of lambdas (e.g., set nlambda=101), and then when you predict set `s=bestlam` and `exact=FALSE`.