# How to specify chosen lambda to fit lasso in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet, lasso-regression

I have found my best lambda(for lasso) through 10 fold cross validation on my training data set and validated with testing dataset. Now I would like to use my best lambda to fit a model on the whole dataset(using both training and test). How do I specify the chosen lambda to fit my Final model.
Can I use the below code?

```
Final_model<-glmnet(x,y,family = "binomial",alpha = 1,lambda=lambda.min)
```

Please help,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here an example of this code working with a `lambda.min` set to 1:

```
library(glmnet)
x=matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
y=rep(0:1,50)
lambda.min=1
Final_model<-glmnet(x,y, family="binomial",alpha = 1,lambda=lambda.min)
Final_model

Call:  glmnet(x = x, y = y, family = "binomial", alpha = 1, lambda = lambda.min) 

     Df       %Dev Lambda
[1,]  0 -1.121e-15      1
```

**Update**

If you have warning messages during the exacution, this could be related to the use of a single lambda value, this is deprecated in the documentation `?glmnet`:

> lambda: A user supplied lambda sequence. Typical usage is to have the
>   program compute its own lambda sequence based on nlambda and
>   lambda.min.ratio. Supplying a value of lambda overrides this. **WARNING:
>   use with care. Avoid supplying a single value for lambda (for
>   predictions after CV use predict() instead)**. Supply instead a
>   decreasing sequence of lambda values. glmnet relies on its warms
>   starts for speed, and its often faster to fit a whole path than
>   compute a single fit.

Related questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101101/convergence-for-1st-lambda-value-not-reached-error-using-glmnet-package-and-sp/151447) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184776/glmnet-not-converging-for-lambda-min-from-cv-glmnet/32185491)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I used it but got a warning. Warning messages:
1: from glmnet Fortran code (error code -1); Convergence for 1th lambda value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
2: In getcoef(fit, nvars, nx, vnames) :
  an empty model has been returned; probably a convergence issue. Some background- Its an heavily imbalanced binary dataset.

Comment: Can you post it and a reproducible example dataset?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the link to similar questions. But there are no answers how to fit the model to the whole data set. They have advised to use the predict() function, but won't that be predicting with the model  from the training data set . The data set is a huge (2000X200000) with both response and predictors are 0,s and 1's. The code is the exact same code as before: Final_model<-glmnet(x,y,family = "binomial",alpha = 1,lambda=lambda.min). Thanks in advance.